# Using getent passwd {1001..} as a subprocess

Tags: python, pycharm, subprocess

I am writing a Python script that creates 33 users through the "useradd" subprocess in Ubuntu. After that I wish to print out the added users by using another subprocess, perferably getent. I want to add {1001..1033} so that the print omits the uneeded information and only shows the users based on UID but do not know how to do it.

I had tried writing "subprocess.run(["getent", "passwd"], {1001..1033})", but that immediately sends of warning signs in Pycharm. Without the "{1001..1033}" the subprocess works, but prints walls of redundant information.

EDIT: Solved thanks to leviant pied.

Comment: `{1001..1033}` is supposed to be expanded by shell, so either run the command with _bash_ explicitly, or construct list of IDs with Python and pass them as all the other args.

Comment: Why call `getent` as a subprocesses when Python provides [`pwd.getpwnam()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pwd.html#pwd.getpwnam) natively?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart they may want [`pwd.getpwuid(uid)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pwd.html#pwd.getpwuid) instead, but good point - I was not aware of Python's `pwd`, thanks for bringing this up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
>>> subprocess.run(['getent', 'passwd'] + list(map(str, range(1001, 1033 + 1))))
CompletedProcess(args=['getent', 'passwd', '1001', '1002', '1003', '1004', '1005', '1006', '1007', '1008', '1009', '1010', '1011', '1012', '1013', '1014', '1015', '1016', '1017', '1018', '1019', '1020', '1021', '1022', '1023', '1024', '1025', '1026', '1027', '1028', '1029', '1030', '1031', '1032', '1033'], returncode=2)
```

Comment: Doing this in Python is way better than expanding it in the shell. Nice.